# Optimization of Long Expressions in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, wolfram-mathematica

I have a question concerning long expressions in C/C++. So I calculated a closed form to a Matrix I need in my code. It is a symmetric 6x6 Matrix. So basically i want to do that

```
void calcMat(double * Mat, const double * S, const double * F, const double * tau, const double * D, const double * G)
{
   //ReadIn all data from the given Arrays into const double's
   const double G1 = G[0]; const double G2 = G[1]; const double G3 = G[2];

   const double F11 = F[0]; const double F12 = F[1]; const double F13 = F[2];
   const double F21 = F[3]; const double F22 = F[4]; const double F23 = F[5];
   const double F31 = F[6]; const double F32 = F[7]; const double F33 = F[8];

   const double sq2 = SQRT2 * 0.5;
   const double S11 = S[0]; const double S12 = sq2 * S[3]; const double S13 = sq2 * S[5];
   const double S22 = S[1]; const double S23 = sq2 * S[4];
   const double S33 = S[2];

   const double t11 = tau[0];
   const double t22 = tau[4];
   const double t33 = tau[8];
   const double t12 = tau[1];
   const double t23 = tau[5];
   const double t13 = tau[2];

   const double Sqr2I = 1. / sqrt(2.);
   const double D1111 = D[0]; const double D1122 = D[1]; const double D1133 = D[2]; const double D1112 = Sqr2I * D[3]; const double D1123 = Sqr2I * D[4]; const double D1113 = Sqr2I * D[5];
   const double D2222 = D[7]; const double D2233 = D[8]; const double D1222 = Sqr2I * D[9]; const double D2223 = Sqr2I*D[10]; const double D1322 = Sqr2I*D[11];
   const double D3333 = D[14]; const double D1233 = Sqr2I * D[15]; 
   const double D2333 = Sqr2I * D[16]; const double D1333 = Sqr2I * D[17];
   const double D1212 = 0.5 * D[21]; const double D1223 = 0.5 * D[22]; 
   const double D1213 = D[23];
   const double D2323 = 0.5 * D[28]; const double D1323 = 0.5 * D[29];
   const double D1313 = 0.5 * D[35];

   //Build Matrix first entry
   Mat[0] += (D1112*F11*G1*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1212*F12*G1*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1213*F13*G1*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1122*F11*G2*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1222*F12*G2*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1322*F13*G2*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1123*F11*G3*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1223*F12*G3*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1323*F13*G3*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1111*F11*G1*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1112*F12*G1*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1113*F13*G1*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1112*F11*G2*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1212*F12*G2*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1213*F13*G2*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1113*F11*G3*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1213*F12*G3*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1313*F13*G3*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1113*F11*G1*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1213*F12*G1*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1313*F13*G1*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1123*F11*G2*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1223*F12*G2*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1323*F13*G2*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1133*F11*G3*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1233*F12*G3*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1333*F13*G3*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)));
   //other terms in a similar fashion
}
```

I can just copy and paste all the += evaluations and that works out fine when I compile with g++ and -O0. But when I enable -O2 the compilation takes extremely long and often I run out of memory on some machines. My question is: Would it help to define each matrix entry in it's own scope and then add in, like

```
void calcMat(double * Mat, other InputArrays)
{
   //ReadIn all data from the given Arrays into const double's
   //as shown above 
   //Build Matrix
   {
     const double Mat0 = (D1112*F11*G1*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1212*F12*G1*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1213*F13*G1*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1122*F11*G2*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1222*F12*G2*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1322*F13*G2*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1123*F11*G3*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1223*F12*G3*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1323*F13*G3*(F12*F12*S12*t11 + F13*F22*S13*t12 + F13*F32*S13*t13 + F11*S11*(F12*t11 + F22*t12 + F32*t13) +
     F12*(F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + 2*F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + 2*F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) + F21*F22*S11*t22 + F22*F22*S12*t22 + F22*F23*S13*t22 + F22*F31*S11*t23 +
     F21*F32*S11*t23 + 2*F22*F32*S12*t23 + F23*F32*S13*t23 + F22*F33*S13*t23 + F32*(F31*S11 + F32*S12 + F33*S13)*t33) +
  D1111*F11*G1*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1112*F12*G1*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1113*F13*G1*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1112*F11*G2*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1212*F12*G2*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1213*F13*G2*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1113*F11*G3*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1213*F12*G3*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1313*F13*G3*(F11*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F21*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F31*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1113*F11*G1*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1213*F12*G1*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1313*F13*G1*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1123*F11*G2*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1223*F12*G2*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1323*F13*G2*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1133*F11*G3*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1233*F12*G3*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)) +
  D1333*F13*G3*(F13*(F11*S11*t11 + F12*S12*t11 + F13*S13*t11 + F21*S11*t12 + F22*S12*t12 + F23*S13*t12 + F31*S11*t13 + F32*S12*t13 + F33*S13*t13) +
     F23*(F11*S11*t12 + F12*S12*t12 + F13*S13*t12 + F21*S11*t22 + F22*S12*t22 + F23*S13*t22 + F31*S11*t23 + F32*S12*t23 + F33*S13*t23) +
     F33*(F11*S11*t13 + F12*S12*t13 + F13*S13*t13 + F21*S11*t23 + F22*S12*t23 + F23*S13*t23 + F31*S11*t33 + F32*S12*t33 + F33*S13*t33)));
     Mat[0] += Mat0;
   } 
   ...
}
```

or is there any other way to help the compiler parse huge expressions?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48568021/edit) and decide on a language.

Comment: Your source code would have to be quite extensive if the -O2 flag was actually causing you to run out of memory on a reasonable modern system.

Comment: [probably you need a math expression reducer like mathcad, mathlab or mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6296837/995714)

Comment: This expressions where generated with mathematica. It could not simplify them more.

Comment: Oh my. You should figure out how to do whatever this computation does in readable C++ code instead of using this auto-generated mess.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions how to improve the C output of Mathematica.

Comment: My question is not to produce the most readable code. This is not the point of that function. My question is whether there is ANY way to help the compiler whilst optimizing

Comment: I think I'd go back to Mathematica and ask it to work a little harder, perhaps persuade it to eliminate common sub-expressions.  For instance, I see terms such as `F33*S13*t13` recurring and you might be able to help the compiler if the code computes these once, outside the humongous statements.  In fact, the more I look the more (a) I see the recurrence of such terms and (b) I go boss-eyed.

Comment: Looks like you could use more temporary variables, for example, the expression `F21*S11*t12` is appearing many times.

Comment: see here.. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25132/2079

Answer (score 2):

Before this gets closed, let me give you a headstart.

If you have only your expression and not the algorithm, how it was constructed, you can still do some optimization. I am taking your large expression for `Mat[0]` and put it into a variable inside Mathematica. The function we are using to optimize common expressions out is this here

```
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[{x^2 Sin[x^2]}]
(*
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[
 Block[{Compile`$125}, 
  Compile`$125 = x^2; {Compile`$125 Sin[Compile`$125]}]]
*)
```

The hope is that we can (a) make your expression smaller and (b) make it easier for the compiler because it might be able to optimized statements better than a large expression.

We can already see that the optimized expression will (even with all the new temporary variables) be smaller by a factor of 6 than what you have now:

```
ByteCount[expr]
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[{expr}] // ByteCount

Out[560]= 64624

Out[561]= 11752
```

Let's try to turn the optimized expression into C code.

```
<< CCodeGenerator`
opt = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[{expr}];
vars = # -> ToString[#] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[Cases[expr, _Symbol, Infinity]]
```

`vars` is a replacement list that has a rule for each variable in your large expression of the form `var -> "var"`. We need this later to create the c-code string. If you look at the optimized expression, you see that it contains a `Block` with variable definitions and a `CompoundExpression` in the body where all the action happens.

First, we will convert all assignments to valid c-declarations and make a c-block.

```
expr1 = opt /. CompoundExpression :> List /. 
       HoldPattern[Block[_, body_]] :> CBlock[body] /. 
      HoldPattern[Set[lhs_, rhs_]] :> 
       CDeclare["const double", CAssign[lhs, rhs]] /. {final_} :> 
      CAssign["Mat[0]", final] /. repl /. vars // First
```

After this, we have many things of the form

```
CDeclare["const double", CAssign["tmp55", "F22" "S12" "t23"]]
```

Important to note is that the operations (like here the multiplication of "F22", "S12" and "t23") are still in there. Those need to be replaced by valid c-operations as well.

```
expr2 = expr1 //. {(h : (Times | Plus))[a__] :> COperator[h, {a}],
   Power[a_, b_] :> CCall["pow", {a, b}]}
```

Now, when the structure is correct, you can turn this into readable c-code

```
ToCCodeString @@ expr2
```

Please note, that I haven't verified that all things I did are correct. I wouldn't even implement it with these replacements, but I just gave it a try and thought what the heck, I can post it as well. The created code reflect in its essence what the Mathematica compiler would do as well. Maybe it helps:

```
const double tmp1 = pow(F12, 2);
const double tmp2 = S12 * t11 * tmp1;
const double tmp3 = F13 * F22 * S13 * t12;
const double tmp4 = F13 * F32 * S13 * t13;
const double tmp5 = F12 * t11;
const double tmp6 = F22 * t12;
const double tmp7 = F32 * t13;
const double tmp8 = tmp5 + tmp6 + tmp7;
const double tmp9 = F11 * S11 * tmp8;
const double tmp10 = F13 * S13 * t11;
const double tmp11 = F21 * S11 * t12;
const double tmp12 = 2 * F22 * S12 * t12;
const double tmp13 = F23 * S13 * t12;
const double tmp14 = F31 * S11 * t13;
const double tmp15 = 2 * F32 * S12 * t13;
const double tmp16 = F33 * S13 * t13;
const double tmp17 = tmp10 + tmp11 + tmp12 + tmp13 + tmp14 + tmp15 + tmp16;
const double tmp18 = F12 * tmp17;
const double tmp19 = F21 * F22 * S11 * t22;
const double tmp20 = pow(F22, 2);
const double tmp21 = S12 * t22 * tmp20;
const double tmp22 = F22 * F23 * S13 * t22;
const double tmp23 = F22 * F31 * S11 * t23;
const double tmp24 = F21 * F32 * S11 * t23;
const double tmp25 = 2 * F22 * F32 * S12 * t23;
const double tmp26 = F23 * F32 * S13 * t23;
const double tmp27 = F22 * F33 * S13 * t23;
const double tmp28 = F31 * S11;
const double tmp29 = F32 * S12;
const double tmp30 = F33 * S13;
const double tmp31 = tmp28 + tmp29 + tmp30;
const double tmp32 = F32 * t33 * tmp31;
const double tmp33 = tmp18 + tmp19 + tmp2 + tmp21 + tmp22 + tmp23 + tmp24 + tmp25 + tmp26 + tmp27 + tmp3 + tmp32 + tmp4 + tmp9;
const double tmp34 = F11 * S11 * t11;
const double tmp35 = F12 * S12 * t11;
const double tmp36 = F22 * S12 * t12;
const double tmp37 = F32 * S12 * t13;
const double tmp38 = tmp10 + tmp11 + tmp13 + tmp14 + tmp16 + tmp34 + tmp35 + tmp36 + tmp37;
const double tmp39 = F11 * tmp38;
const double tmp40 = F11 * S11 * t12;
const double tmp41 = F12 * S12 * t12;
const double tmp42 = F13 * S13 * t12;
const double tmp43 = F21 * S11 * t22;
const double tmp44 = F22 * S12 * t22;
const double tmp45 = F23 * S13 * t22;
const double tmp46 = F31 * S11 * t23;
const double tmp47 = F32 * S12 * t23;
const double tmp48 = F33 * S13 * t23;
const double tmp49 = tmp40 + tmp41 + tmp42 + tmp43 + tmp44 + tmp45 + tmp46 + tmp47 + tmp48;
const double tmp50 = F21 * tmp49;
const double tmp51 = F11 * S11 * t13;
const double tmp52 = F12 * S12 * t13;
const double tmp53 = F13 * S13 * t13;
const double tmp54 = F21 * S11 * t23;
const double tmp55 = F22 * S12 * t23;
const double tmp56 = F23 * S13 * t23;
const double tmp57 = F31 * S11 * t33;
const double tmp58 = F32 * S12 * t33;
const double tmp59 = F33 * S13 * t33;
const double tmp60 = tmp51 + tmp52 + tmp53 + tmp54 + tmp55 + tmp56 + tmp57 + tmp58 + tmp59;
const double tmp61 = F31 * tmp60;
const double tmp62 = tmp39 + tmp50 + tmp61;
const double tmp63 = F13 * tmp38;
const double tmp64 = F23 * tmp49;
const double tmp65 = F33 * tmp60;
const double tmp66 = tmp63 + tmp64 + tmp65;
Mat[0] = D1112 * F11 * G1 * tmp33 + D1212 * F12 * G1 * tmp33 + D1213 * F13 * G1 * tmp33 + D1122 * F11 * G2 * tmp33 + D1222 * F12 * G2 * tmp33 + D1322 * F13 * G2 * tmp33 + D1123 * F11 * G3 * tmp33 + D1223 * F12 * G3 * tmp33 + D1323 * F13 * G3 * tmp33 + D1111 * F11 * G1 * tmp62 + D1112 * F12 * G1 * tmp62 + D1113 * F13 * G1 * tmp62 + D1112 * F11 * G2 * tmp62 + D1212 * F12 * G2 * tmp62 + D1213 * F13 * G2 * tmp62 + D1113 * F11 * G3 * tmp62 + D1213 * F12 * G3 * tmp62 + D1313 * F13 * G3 * tmp62 + D1113 * F11 * G1 * tmp66 + D1213 * F12 * G1 * tmp66 + D1313 * F13 * G1 * tmp66 + D1123 * F11 * G2 * tmp66 + D1223 * F12 * G2 * tmp66 + D1323 * F13 * G2 * tmp66 + D1133 * F11 * G3 * tmp66 + D1233 * F12 * G3 * tmp66 + D1333 * F13 * G3 * tmp66;
```